# What is the meaning of the below sentence in c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++'s “placement new”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new)

in the below code what does Line 3 represents, is it the way of typecasting? or what

```
 void someCode()
 {
   char memory[sizeof(Fred)];     // Line #1
   void* place = memory;          // Line #2

   Fred* f = new(place) Fred();   // Line #3
   // The pointers f and place will be equal

   ...
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of alignment requirements. The `Fred` type might require stricter alignment than `char`. You should use `aligned_storage` instead, available in C++11 and TR1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical usage of **[Placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10)**.
It allows you to allocate memory and then construct objects at that particular memory location.

Line #3 essentially just calls the constructor `Fred::Fred()`. The `this` pointer in the `Fred` constructor will be equal to `place`. The returned pointer `f` will therefore be equal to `place`.

Comment: Hey Als, thanks for your response...how can this pointer i.e pointer to Fred will be equal to void*?,

Comment: @LLL: This is what the implementation of placement new does for you.It  assigns the address of `place` to `f`. This is a functionality provided by the placement new.

Comment: Thnx for clarification.. this s wat i wanted..